# Como alterar um conteúdo dinâmico de um template quando o usuário clicar em um botão?

Tags: java, primefaces

Gostaria que o meio da página fosse alterado quando o usuário clicasse em "login" ou em "registro". Alguém consegue me explicar como posso fazer isto?

Se conhecerem tutorias que ensinem como fazer o login e se puderem deixar os links dos mesmos eu agradeceria.

[image: imagem]

Código da página:

```jsp
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Meu Sistema</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div align="center">
            <p:layout style="min-width:1020px;max-width:1020px;min-height:600px">   
                <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                    <ui:insert name="centro">
                        O que estiver aqui será substituido!
                    </ui:insert>
                </p:layoutUnit>  
            </p:layout>  
        </div>
        <p:stack icon="imagens/stacks.png" expanded="true">
    <p:menuitem value="Login" icon="imagens/lock.png" url="#"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Registar" icon="imagens/register.png" url="#"/>
</p:stack>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

Definir um bean(com `@SessionScoped` ou `@ApplicationScoped`) para controlar qual página será exibida.

E no seu xhtml:

```
<ui:insert name="centro">
    <ui:include src="#{seuBean.pagina}"/>
</ui:insert>
```

Sendo `pagina`(uma String) o caminho do arquivo.

E quando quiser trocar de página só setar o novo caminho na variável `pagina`  e atualizar o 'centro'.
Exemplo:

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{seu.trocarParaLogin()}" value="Login"/>

 //método
 public void trocarParaLogin() {
     setPagina("SUA PAGINA");
 }
```

Possíveis problemas, usando esse método, você não terá a opção de voltar/avançar no navegador porque você ainda está na mesma página.
E se você usar beans `@ViewEscoped` eles não serão destruídos ao trocar o conteúdo do 'centro'.

Comment: E como que eu mando o link para a variavel pagina?

Comment: editei a minha resposta, da uma olhada.

Comment: Eu entendi tudo o que voce disse mas o include nao esta a fazer o refresh eu estou a fazer assim `<p:menuitem value="Login" icon="imagens/lock.png" url="#"
   actionListener="#{Controlomenu.Paginalogin}" update="centro" />` em que **centro** e o nome de um panelgroup

Comment: Achei que esse post responde exatamente a pergunta. Porém, na minha opinião, não é uma boa prática e não faz parte do conceito de templates JSF.